# Printing last name + first name - but it shows error (Java)

Tags: java, string

So I have made a code for user to enter their first and last name; then exhanging the two position.

for example. Bulota Babi becomes Babi, Bulota

this is my code

```
public class trial {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = sc.nextLine();

        String fname = input.substring(0, input.indexOf(0));
        String lname = input.substring(1, input.indexOf(input.length()));

        System.out.println(lname +","+ fname);
    }

}
```

im not sure whats wrong with it, this is the error message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1967)
    at trial.main(trial.java:11)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Comment: input.index(0) returns -1. So it throws the above exception.

Comment: Confirm if the input contains a character with ASCI value 0. If it doesn't, cater for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better to just use `String.split`

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = sc.nextLine();

    String arr[] = input.split (" ");
    if (arr.length > 1)
        System.out.println(arr[1] +","+ arr[0]);
}
```

With your solution, it is trying to find a char with the ascii value `0` which of course is returning `-1` as it does not exist - hence your substring is failing

**edit**

To answer your comment below

```
         String in = "John Appleseed William";
         String arr[] = in.split (" ");
         if (arr.length == 2) {
             System.out.println(arr[1] + ", " + arr[0]);
         }
         if (arr.length == 3) {
             System.out.println(arr[2] + ", " + arr[0] + " " + arr[1]);
         }
```

Comment: I thought of posting the answer with `split` and you did it.. BTW, I didn't downvote.. :)

Comment: Got it, but how do you accound say if they have a middle name, like John Appleseed William and you want to print William, John Appleseed?

Answer (score 1):

Let say you have an input string "Bulota Babi".

```
String fname = input.substring(0, input.indexOf(" "));
String lname = input.substring(input.indexOf(" "), input.length());
```

Comment: I thought the indexOf what looking for each word. I was mistaken, turn out its looking of each character in the string. I get it now :)

Answer (score 0):

The `input.indexOf(0)` command is looking for the index of the char which has the ASCII value `0`. As it is not found, it returns the value `-1`.

The indexOf is made to look for the place of a character in a String. You can't use it by giving it a number, unless it is the character ASCII value

Comment: oh yes, I see what you mean. I thought the indexOf is looking for words that have index

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `substring` method. It needs start and end positions of string to cut out from:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = sc.nextLine();

        int coma = input.indexOf(' ');
        String fname = input.substring(0, coma);
        String lname = input.substring(coma + 1, input.length());

        System.out.println(lname + "," + fname);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `String.indexOf` function works on the ASCII value. As you are passing 0 in indexOf function it  returns value `-1`.

After that you are doing subString on input string having range (0,-1).

> As Mentioned in [java docs for java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) , java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
>   Exception will come to indicate that an index is either negative or
>   greater than the size of the string.

So your exception is coming from  **input.substring** function